# Using p:resetInput along with Spring bean in PrimeFaces 3.5

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use [`<p:resetInput>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf) as it stands for. This works fine until I annotate a JSF bean with `@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`.

The XHTML page:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="true">
        <p:panel id="panel" header="New" style="margin-bottom:10px;" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal">  
            <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid" columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="txtName" value="State *" />
                <p:inputText id="txtName" value="#{testManagedBean.txtName}" label="Name" required="true" maxlength="45">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="45" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="txtName"/>                    
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="panel" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.submit}" type="submit" ajax="true" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="panel" process="@this">  
                <p:resetInput target="panel" />  
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The JSF managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class TestManagedBean
{
     private String txtName;

     //Setters and getters.
}
```

---

When I have this JSF bean annotated with `@Controller` like so,

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class TestManagedBean
{
     private String txtName;

     //Setters and getters.
}
```

This doesn't work and the value of the only UIInput component, `<p:inputText>` is not reset to `null`, when the button to reset the value is pressed.

---

This even doesn't work with `actionListener` like,

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" update="panel" process="@this" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.reset()}" >  
    <p:resetInput target="panel" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

and in the JSF managed bean the `reset()` method is defined as follows.

```
public void reset()
{
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("form:panel"); 
}
```

---

Hence, at last, I only left with the following option in managed bean.

```
public void reset()
{
    txtName=null;
}
```

Manually resetting the value.

Is there a way to make `<p:resetInput>` work as it stands for?

Comment: Why do you keep mixing JSF and Spring bean management annotations in an incorrect assumption that they understand each other? You were also consistently doing that in all your previous questions. The Spring-specific bean registration annotation `@Controller` defaults to application scope, yet you're somehow expecting that JSF-specific bean scope annotation `@RequestScoped` is magically recognized by Spring. You should instead be using Spring's own scope annotation and *get rid* of the both JSF bean management annotations as they have totally no effect and are only more confusing to maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, when I changed the managed bean like so,

```
@Controller
@Scope("view")
public final class testManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<Bean> implements Serializable
{
    private String txtName; //Getter and setter.
}
```

as the comment implies. Afterwards, the view scope is defined as [this](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/) blog indicates.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" update="panel" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.submit}" icon="ui-icon-check" type="submit" ajax="true" value="Save"/>

<p:commandButton value="Reset" update="panel" process="@this">
    <p:resetInput target="panel" />
</p:commandButton>
```

`actionListener` is unnecessary in this case. So, it is removed from the reset button.

<sub>I just answered by cut & pasting the last edit in the question to remove the question from the [unanswered question list](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).</sub>